# MongoDB terminate connection after successfully authenticated from Robo 3T

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

MongoDB Version: v4.2.7

Robo 3T Version: v1.3.1

There are two users in the db admin, one with build-in role "userAdminAnyDatabase" and the other one with "readAnyDatabase". I can use the user with "userAdminAnyDatabase" role to connect to the mongodb through Robo 3T without any issue. However, when I use the user with "readAnyDatabase", I couldn't connect to the mongodb with below error.

[image]

Below is the log on MongoDB when I initiate the connection. It instantly terminated the session after it has been authenticated.

```
2020-09-28T17:37:57.065+0800 I  NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 10.212.135.200:57344 #23102882 (554 connections now open)
2020-09-28T17:37:57.066+0800 I  NETWORK  [conn23102882] received client metadata from 10.212.135.200:57344 conn23102882: { application: { name: "MongoDB Shell" }, driver: { name: "MongoDB Internal Client", version: "4.0.5-17-gd808df2233" }, os: { type: "Windows", name: "Microsoft Windows 8", architecture: "x86_64", version: "6.2 (build 9200)" } }
2020-09-28T17:37:57.125+0800 I  ACCESS   [conn23102882] Successfully authenticated as principal soc on admin from client 10.212.135.200:57344
2020-09-28T17:37:57.170+0800 I  NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 10.212.135.200:57345 #23102883 (555 connections now open)
2020-09-28T17:37:57.171+0800 I  NETWORK  [conn23102883] received client metadata from 10.212.135.200:57345 conn23102883: { application: { name: "robo3t" }, driver: { name: "MongoDB Internal Client", version: "4.0.5-17-gd808df2233" }, os: { type: "Windows", name: "Microsoft Windows 8", architecture: "x86_64", version: "6.2 (build 9200)" } }
2020-09-28T17:37:57.224+0800 I  NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 10.212.135.200:57346 #23102884 (556 connections now open)
2020-09-28T17:37:57.225+0800 I  NETWORK  [conn23102884] received client metadata from 10.212.135.200:57346 conn23102884: { application: { name: "MongoDB Shell" }, driver: { name: "MongoDB Internal Client", version: "4.0.5-17-gd808df2233" }, os: { type: "Windows", name: "Microsoft Windows 8", architecture: "x86_64", version: "6.2 (build 9200)" } }
2020-09-28T17:37:57.283+0800 I  ACCESS   [conn23102884] Successfully authenticated as principal soc on admin from client 10.212.135.200:57346
2020-09-28T17:37:57.320+0800 I  NETWORK  [conn23102882] end connection 10.212.135.200:57344 (555 connections now open)
2020-09-28T17:37:57.339+0800 I  NETWORK  [conn23102883] end connection 10.212.135.200:57345 (554 connections now open)
2020-09-28T17:37:57.512+0800 I  NETWORK  [conn23102884] end connection 10.212.135.200:57346 (553 connections now open)
```

I tried to add a set name to the connection as the error prompt and the connection time is much longer than the last one and also the error is a bit different.

[image]

```
2020-09-28T17:58:34.823+0800 I  NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 10.212.135.200:57925 #23118931 (587 connections now open)
2020-09-28T17:58:34.833+0800 I  NETWORK  [conn23118931] received client metadata from 10.212.135.200:57925 conn23118931: { application: { name: "MongoDB Shell" }, driver: { name: "MongoDB Internal Client", version: "4.0.5-17-gd808df2233" }, os: { type: "Windows", name: "Microsoft Windows 8", architecture: "x86_64", version: "6.2 (build 9200)" } }
2020-09-28T17:58:34.893+0800 I  ACCESS   [conn23118931] Successfully authenticated as principal soc on admin from client 10.212.135.200:57925
```

Maybe I have misconfigured anything? Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

For the first error, provide replica set name in configuration.

For the second error, you have the host names wrong perhaps.

Verify connection works using `mongo` shell.

Comment: But the problem is that when I use the user with "userAdminAnyDatabase", I can log in without any problem. This problem only appears when I use the user with "readAnyDatabase". So I don't think it is because of the wrong hostname. I tried to use mongo shell to login (with the problematic user) and everything is fine and I can even query some data from the collections

Comment: Authentication is not needed or used to determine replica set name. Try some other roles.